# jQuery ajax request from local file (Origin 'null' not allowed access)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am making a jQuery ajax call from a local file which retrieves JSON data from a webserver:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mywebsite.com/data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: showData
});
```

and I am getting the following error on chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mywebsite.com/data.json. No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have read through a lot of other answers which seem to come to the conclusion that you cannot make ajax requests from local files with chrome, so the solutions are:

- Host the file making the request on the sever
- Run chrome with the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag

but neither of these options are suitable for me.

However, when I host the JSON data on another site (myjson.com), so that the line in the ajax request reads

```
url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/myfile'
```

the file loads perfectly and the data is correctly displayed.

Why is the ajax request allowed to 'myjson.com' but not to 'mywebsite.com'?

Edit:

I have the line

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

in my apache2.conf file

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a `.htaccess` file in your document root and add the following lines to it:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

What the above lines do is, they allow Cross origin resource sharing for all domains on .json files thus removing the error.

Comment: I already have that line in my apache2.conf file on the server. Do I need it in the .htaccess as well?

Comment: Is Apache mod_headers module enabled ??